# Spring3 Validation with MongoDB: ValidatingMongoEventListener doesn't work

Tags: spring, mongodb, validation, postman, spring-3

I want to validate @Documents in spring3 whith mongoDB, but my mongo configuration doesn't work.

this is my configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfig {

    // ...
    @Bean
    public ValidatingMongoEventListener validatingMongoEventListener() {
        return new ValidatingMongoEventListener(validator());
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }

}
```

this is my model:

```
@Document(collection = "vehicleFleet")
@Getter
@Setter
public class VehicleFleetModel {

    @Id
    //@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String id_VehicleFleet;

    @NotNull(message = "name must not be null ")
    String name;

    private List<VehicleModel> vehicles= new ArrayList<>();

    @Size(max = 100, message = "tag length must be less than or equal to 100")
    private String tag;
    //TAGS? --> chiedere a valerio///////////////////

}
```

my pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I try to create new model with wrong inputs from postman but in each case the document is created. I would like if I set incorrect elements the document will not be created.